# Input value atttribute not working with ng-model in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, post

I am currently working on an app, in which you can edit items, which will be updated in a DB. Because I don't want people to submit empty forms, I prepopulate the inputs with the current item.

```
form.form-update(method="post", ng-repeat='item in items', autocomplete="off" ng-submit='edit()')
        .form-group
            label(for='key') Key:
            input.form-control(type="text" id="key" ng-init="key.updateKey='{{item.key}}' " value='{{item.key}}' name='keyUpdate' ng-model='key.updateKey')`
.form-group
            button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit") Save
            a.btn(href='/') Cancel`
```

Now when I submit this as an empty Form, I don't get the old data saved, but {{item.key}} in the Database.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just found out, what was causing the error. It turns out that you dont neet the {{}}, so it turns into this:

```
input.form-control(type="text" id="key" ng-init="key.updateKey=item.key", name='keyUpdate' ng-model='key.updateKey')
```